# Testing and Deployment workflow (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, continuous-deployment

Not sure if this is in the correct section or not - let me know if not.

I’m completely new to testing and deployment in a production environment (live web app), and have recently joined a team who have the following setup.

They currently have test server X which can be viewed live at x.website.com, and production server Y which is viewed at website.com.

Our main tasks as developers is to work through GitHub issues, which vary from being small changes like front-end stuff (editing an incorrect link for example), to larger backend modifications.

Currently their system for testing is to push up Issue_X to the remote git branch on server X for live testing, and get one of the team testers to have a look at it.  If a person has been working on a series of small issues, they will often merge them into a batch and push them up together for testing - but it’s often at the discretion of the dev whether they think the issues are small enough to be merged together.  Other times, when a dev worked on a larger issue, the test server may be out of limits for a good while, whilst testing is ongoing.  Either way - the test server is only useable by one dev at a time.  This is further prolonged by the fact that many of our team (and all testers) are volunteers so aren’t always available.

My question is - how does this compare to the industry standard?  It seems like quite an inefficient and inconsistent way of doing it. What are the alternatives?

Comment: There are those who say, if you practiced TDD and had wall-to-wall automated tests, where Rails shines, you would not need to branch your codebase, ever. Do you have automated tests?

Comment: I think they have a few scattered rspec tests but it's not system wide - and I don't think they're automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very inefficient to do testing this way.  Normally when people say "test" it's often unit testing done through a gem (Capybara or RSpec).  This practice of having test server is often called a staging server where that's the last step to catch any bugs before deployed on live.

It's very worrying that only one test is allowed on your staging server, is there any reason for this?

Alternatives will be to use a testing gem like I mentioned above to test the data and endpoints of the API.  Frontend is a bit more trickier to write tests for but there are frameworks for that like Mocha and Karma.

Comment: I should have clarified - when I say testing I do mean staging, but in our team we say "ready for testing" when the dev has pushed up any changes - so it's user testing I'm referring to I guess.  But I suppose ideally, a unit test should be written for any corresponding changes.

There's only one test / change allowed on the staging server simply because of the system in place which I described I guess... I think it may be because it could get messy if multiple devs are pushing up untested code to the same branch?